# Получение моделей Laravel 4.2 и разбивка на части. Вопрос о верстке Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, laravel

Есть задача вывести, условно, популярные товары в карусель как [тут](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-moving-box-carousel). 
Т.е. разбивка на блоки по 4 модели из коллекции, каждый из которых, при показе принимает параметр «active».

Как разбить на части всю коллекцию в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

А он что, частями запрашивает каждый раз по 4 через ajax запрос?

Тогда доставать данные нужно с методом **Model::paginate(4)**. И каждый раз в GET параметрах передавать параметр **page** постоянно его увеличивая на единицу. Laravel всё остальное делает за вас. Это базовая пагинация.

Если слайдер отрисовывает всю коллекцию сразу, то ничего делать не надо, он должен сам разбивать данные по 4 на слайд.

Comment: Спасибо! Не сработало :(